# How Do I Use OnModelCreating Inside the Model itself in Entity Framework Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, model, entity-framework-core

I'm very new to Entity Framework, so go easy on me, but I would like to keep the fluent API for my models a little closer to usage and put it inside the model object itself. I couldn't find anything in the documentation or via Google search for a built in way to do this, so I thought perhaps I could just call a static method on the model if it exists from the `DbContext.OnModelCreating()` method. Here's what I come up with, but it doesn't seem to work whenever I run `Add-Migration`, and `Script-Migration`, even if I remove all migrations first. Any idea where I'm going wrong on this? or perhaps a better way to do it?

Trademark.cs (the model)

```
public class Trademark
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ... 
    protected static void OnModelCreating( ModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Trademark>().HasIndex(x=>x.Name).IsUnique();
    }
}
```

PartDbContext.cs (`DbContext`)

```
public class PartDbContext: DbContext
{
    // ...
    public DbSet<Trademark> Trademarks { get; set; }
    public PartDbContext( DbContextOptions options ): base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating( ModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        dynamic m = modelBuilder.Model.GetType().GetMethod("OnModelCreating",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
        if( m != null )
            m.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

I'm thinking the issue is that `modelBuilder.Model.GetType()` returns `typeof(IMutableModel)` and not `typeof(Trademark)`. So, perhaps I just need to know how to get the type of the model of the model from `modelBuilder`.

Note: If I put `modelBuilder.Entity<Trademark>().HasIndex(x => x.Name).IsUnique();` inside `PartDbContext.OnModelCreating()`, the unique constraint is added. So, I know I at least got that bit correct.

## ***UPDATE***

For anyone else interested in doing this, I decided to narrow the usage down a bit more and only pass the `EntityTypeBuilder` instead of the whole `ModelBuilder`.

PartDbContext.cs

```
protected override void OnModelCreating( ModelBuilder modelBuilder )
{
    foreach( var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes() )
    {
        var method = entityType.ClrType.GetMethod("OnEntityCreating",BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if( method != null )
        {
            var entityBuilder = new object[] {
                typeof(ModelBuilder)
                .GetMethod("Entity",new Type[]{})
                .MakeGenericMethod(entityType.ClrType)
                .Invoke(modelBuilder,null)
            };
            method.Invoke(null,entityBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

Trademark.cs

```
public class Trademark
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    protected static void OnEntityCreating( EntityTypeBuilder<Trademark> entityBuilder )
    {
        entityBuilder.HasIndex(x=>x.Name).IsUnique();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate all [discovered entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-types) and invoke the custom method (if defined) via reflection:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var parameters = new object[] { modelBuilder };
    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        var method = entityType.ClrType.GetMethod("OnModelCreating", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (method != null)
            method.Invoke(null, parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly are these codes doing ? find all dbsets and generates they on db ?

Comment: @MuratCanOĞUZHAN Finds all **discovered** entity types (by convention from `DbSet`s and navigation properties as explained in [Including & Excluding Types - Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-types) section of the documentation).